# Is there a way to keep the sharing condition applied to copied sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So this is my script for copying spreadsheets and renaming them from my current sheet but I need to keep the sharing conditions while copying. By sharing conditions I mean the tick in the box appears when you press make copy for a spreadsheet. I am kind of beginner in coding and searched for help but could not reach a thing.

```js
function Copy_Rename_Sheet() {
  var trial = '123456';
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(trial);
  var lr = spreadSheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 1; i <= lr; i++) {
    //Make a copy of the template file
    var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(trial).makeCopy().getId();
    //Rename the copied file
    var Name = spreadSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(Name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that your goal is to copy the file sharing permissions while duplicating the file in [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app); in a similar way as the user interface allows you the option *Share it with the same people* while copying documents. If that is right, then you are very close to reaching your goal.

First you would need to read the permissions of the file. It's better to do that operation using [Drive API from the Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive), because that way you will have better control of your permissions. You can see here how to activate [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). Then you can [get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/get) a list of every permission affecting the file, but please remember to use the character `*` on the `field` request parameter to make sure that you receive a full response.

Then you can iterate that [response](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions#resource) to determine the permission `role`, its `type` and `emailAddress` of the user. On each iteration you could [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) an identical permission on the new file. If you have any additional doubt, feel free to ask me to clarify.